# Connecting to MS SQL Server using FreeTDS: Error 20002: "Adaptive Server connection failed"

Tags: sql-server, freetds

I am trying to use FreeTDS to connect from a Linux server (RHEL v7) to a separate server running MS SQL Server 2014. However, when attempting to connect with tsql I get the following errors (error message differs depending on whether I include username and password):

```
$ tsql -S MYSERVER
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
        Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
$ tsql -S MYSERVER -U myusername -P mypassword
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20017 (severity 9):
        Unexpected EOF from the server
Error 20002 (severity 9):
        Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

Additionally, running tsql -LH gives no output:

```
$ tsql -LH MYSERVER
$
```

I don't believe the issue is with a firewall or anything else on the SQL Server side, because:

1. I am able to telnet to the server:

   ```
   $ telnet my.server.address 1433
   Trying 11.22.33.444...
   Connected to my.server.address.
   ```
2. And, I can successfully connect to the SQL Server via ODBC from a (Windows) laptop, via the ODBC Data Source Administrator utility.

Contents of my /etc/freetds.conf:

```
[global]
  tds version = 7.0
; tds version = 4.2
...
[MYSERVER]
  host = my.server.address
  port = 1433
  tds version = 7.0
```

Contents of TDSDUMP log file after running tsql -S MYSERVER:

```
log.c:167:Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.95.19
  on 2015-11-18 10:02:20 with debug flags 0x4fff.
iconv.c:328:tds_iconv_open(0x1c53d90, UTF-8)
iconv.c:187:local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1
iconv.c:187:local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE
iconv.c:346:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:348:preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:395:preparing iconv for "ISO-8859-1" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:400:tds_iconv_open: done
net.c:202:Connecting to 11.22.33.444 port 1433 (TDS version 7.0)
net.c:274:tds_open_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"
net.c:313:tds_open_socket() succeeded
util.c:165:Changed query state from DEAD to IDLE
login.c:797:using GSS authentication
gssapi.c:218:using kerberos name MSSQLSvc/my.server.address:1433
gssapi.c:230:gss_import_name: GSS_S_COMPLETE: gss_import_name completed successfully.
gssapi.c:318:gss_init_sec_context: actual mechanism at 0x(nil)
gssapi.c:334:gss_init_sec_context: min_stat 2529639136 "Unknown error -1765328160"
gssapi.c:374:gss_init_sec_context: GSS_S_FAILURE: The routine failed for reasons that are not defined at the GSS level.
login.c:472:login packet rejected
query.c:3769:tds_disconnect()
util.c:165:Changed query state from IDLE to DEAD
util.c:322:tdserror(0x1c53ca0, 0x1c53d90, 20002, 0)
util.c:352:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:375:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
mem.c:648:tds_free_all_results()
```

Comment: I would like to know that!

Answer (score 0):

just remove special character from password and try again , i got the same problem and solve this way

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `freetds.conf` file. It's in `/usr/local/etc/ or /etc/freedts/`.

add:

```
encryption = off
```

If your SQL Server is the old version.